# How does my app know if any incoming call coming to phone in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

My app is running on the foreground and the phone getting a incoming call. In the scenario, the phone is not raising any event to app like deactivated or closing. How do I identify my app not running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You app actually is still the current foreground app (so, kind of running, but audio/video is paused for obvious reasons).

You will get an Obscured event in the app, but you can't distinguish if this due to an incoming call, an incoming SMS, toast or reminder.

Here is [a link to the MSDN documentation of the Obscured event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) you get. There is a corresponding Unobscured event you can also detect.

Comment: For toast message it is not raising any Obscured event but for incoming call and reminders it is raising.